# 3 times fail then lock

Tags: linux, centos

yesterday i fail to login to my server because of bad password three times. Than no one from my IP can log to the system.

how to unlock it and how to set up rule like that? and other rule like if someone fail to login x time than lock that account.

ps : my server running with centos OS.

Comment: are you using fail2ban ?

Comment: You describe two different scenarios in the above question: that three bad attempts lock further login attempts from the source IP, and that three bad attempts lock further login attempts to that account.  Which do you want to do?  Plus, are we talking ssh logins only, or are you looking for a more generally-valid technique?

Comment: yes. its ssh login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to your CentOS Server from Different ISP IP:

Flush all current rules in IPTables:

```
iptables -F
```

Then, install CSF:

```
yum -y install perl-libwww-perl && \
wget http://www.configserver.com/free/csf.tgz && \
tar -xzf csf.tgz && \
cd csf && \
sh install.sh
```

Then open /etc/csf/csf.conf

Change the value of TESTING to 0 from 1

So it should be like this:

```
TESTING = "0"
```

Then confirm the value of LF_DAEMON with 1

So it should be like this:

```
LF_DAEMON = "1"
```

Then change the value of LF_SSHD [Enable login failure detection of sshd connections]

Then,

```
/etc/init.d/csf restart
```

Comment: hmm, with no reference, there could be anything in this free code..  Tempting, but i need to see the code first.  I would be careful blindly installing something like this.
Looks like the url is bad anyway.